# How long should it take to generate a Hydro Network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro

How long should the geoprocessing take to generate a geometric Hydro Network for a fairly large watershed, using ArcHydro?

I have ~ 53,000 DrainageLine segments in the stream layer.  I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 on a laptop with a 2.4 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM.

The Hydro Network Generation tool ran for a few hours, I stopped it, and it looked like about 20% of the network was generated, so I went ahead and tried again. I'm just wondering what to expect time-wise.

Finally finished after 24 hours.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. The answer will vary according to the computing power of your workstation and the complexity of the network.  Without knowing these things (and the quality of the network data, and the version of ArcGIS), this is more like an opinion poll than a question.  In theory, seeking this sort of feedback would be a perfect use of the [chat] feature, but it has a minimum reputation requirement, and it isn't all that active (most folks come here for answers, not to hang out)

Comment: Good point.  I apologize for being vague.  For what it's worth, I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 on a laptop with a 2.4 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM.  I just did a check on ArcGIS Desktop Help and see I'm at the bare minimum for RAM.  I guess I should switch computers for this task, and see about adding memory to the laptop.  The network is for a mountain region, so the streams are fairly bifurcated so I assume it's quite a complex network.

Comment: It sounds like your laptop might be able to complete this processing task if you let it run overnight. Make sure it's plugged in and set to not fall asleep when left unattended. But if you do this sort of geoprocessing task often, your hardware is really going to slow you down.

Comment: My work laptop is 4x2.9Ghz, 16Gb RAM, and 2x1000Gb SSD.  4Gb of RAM is 4-12Gb too little.  The price (and storage) capacity of SSDs have come down (and up) to the point that not having <1ms seek time on disk is throwing a way 90% of the capacity of the system.  In the future, please [edit] the question to provide details, since that's where they're expected to be when folks read the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [help file](http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/Tutorial/Doc/Arc%20Hydro%20Tools%202.0%20-%20Tutorial.pdf) I see the Hydro Network Generation tool is creating a geometric network. It should not be taking hours for 53,000 lines, minutes may be, but not hours.

So this strongly points to your system being the bottle neck. I would follow the advice above, take the hit and run it over night fully expecting not to have completed by the next day or move your processing to a faster machine. That said you have 4GB of ram and a reasonable processor which suggests it's the hard disk, network connection or your laptop is bloated with other applications fighting for resources. You are not one of these people who has email open, 10 tabs on chrome, facebook, twitter, slack, skype, boinc and itunes all running at the same time...? ;)